# MATLAB plot for increasing value

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following matlab script:

```
    %sniffer
close all

%initial conditions:
X0=0; R0=0;
x0=[X0 R0];
%parameters:
k1=1; k2=1; k3=1; k4=0.2;
par=[k1 k2 k3 k4];
%input:
tu=[  0   , 0
      1   , 0
      1.01, 1
     20   , 1
     20.01, 0
     30   , 0
     30.01, 1
     40   , 1
     40.01, 1.2
     50   , 1.2
     50.01, 1.4
     60   , 1.4
     60.01, 0
     70   , 0];

[t,x] = ode45(@sniffer_ode,[0 70],x0, [],par,tu);

S = interp1(tu(:,1),tu(:,2),t);
x = [x S];

plot(t,x, 'LineWidth',3);
xlabel('time (t)')
legend('X','R','S')
```

I want k4 to go from 0.2 to 2.0 in stepsize of 0.2, so `k4=0.2:0.2:2` and make a plot of each step. So only k4 should change, and 10 plots should be made. I wanted to use a for loop, and I know how I can make stepsizes but I don't know how to plot this using the for loop.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot will always plot in the active axes (`gca`) of the active figure (`gcf`) by default. If you issue multiple plots, they will overwrite the previous one by default. To inhibit this, you should call `hold on` before recalling the plot commands.

I suggest starting with `figure; gca; hold on;` (this will always create a new figure window first, then set `hold` for its single new axes; even without the `close all` you have there), then writing a `for k4=...` containing your current plot commands as they are. This will overlap each new plot on the same axes.

```
%initial conditions:
X0=0; R0=0;
x0=[X0 R0];
%parameters:
k1=1; k2=1; k3=1; % k4=0.2:0.2:2

figure;
gca;
hold on;

for k4=0.2:0.2:2
  par=[k1 k2 k3 k4];
  %input:
  tu=[  0   , 0
        1   , 0
        1.01, 1
       20   , 1
       20.01, 0
       30   , 0
       30.01, 1
       40   , 1
       40.01, 1.2
       50   , 1.2
       50.01, 1.4
       60   , 1.4
       60.01, 0
       70   , 0];

  [t,x] = ode45(@sniffer_ode,[0 70],x0, [],par,tu);

  S = interp1(tu(:,1),tu(:,2),t);
  x = [x S];

  plot(t,x, 'LineWidth',3);
  xlabel('time (t)')
  legend('X','R','S')
end %end loop over k4
```

Comment: How do I get the plots with the different k4 values then? I can't really follow what you are saying. Could you explain it using code?

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: Snap! My answer went in at almost exactly the same time as your edit

Comment: @am304, indeed, sorry for the clash:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want all 10 plots on the same figure, you're probably looking at something like that:

```
%sniffer
close all

%initial conditions:
X0=0; R0=0;
x0=[X0 R0];

%input:
tu=[  0   , 0
      1   , 0
      1.01, 1
     20   , 1
     20.01, 0
     30   , 0
     30.01, 1
     40   , 1
     40.01, 1.2
     50   , 1.2
     50.01, 1.4
     60   , 1.4
     60.01, 0
     70   , 0];

%parameters:
k1=1; k2=1; k3=1; k4=0.2:0.2:2;

figure

for k=1:length(k4)
    par=[k1 k2 k3 k4(k)];

    [t,x] = ode45(@sniffer_ode,[0 70],x0, [],par,tu);

    S = interp1(tu(:,1),tu(:,2),t);
    x = [x S];

    plot(t,x, 'LineWidth',3);
    xlabel('time (t)')
    %legend('X','R','S')
    hold on

end
```